Assertion Signature not getting verified even with correct configurations
XMLJS0013: Cryptographic error: Invalid digest for uri '#DUO_5c33136c718660ae8xxxxxxxxxxx'. Calculated digest is h3x5++/BA9QucKG/WoD6e5Hp0MO0EpoJ9TuehF9vmBg= but the xml to validate supplies digest vE5BYzUakCRMsfMw4P+bjvnI8j4KaqSEpIenJaEiWjc=
I am currently using Duo Security along with SAML Authentication Source as Okta in Duo itself. My Service Provider is my customized application where I have feature to integrate with SAML 2.0 Auth. I am using xml-crypto lib in Nodejs for verification of response and assertions
I have verified the certificates coming as response and the certificate I linked with the user request but then also its failing as the above error.
I have tried enabling different combinations of signing response and assertion but then also when checking in https://samltool.io/, its saying invalid assertion signature, XMLJS0013: Cryptographic error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
